# BINDでホスト名が過去の名前のままとなってしまう

Tags: dns

正引きしたホスト名が過去のゾーンファイルに書かれた内容になってしまいます。

`/var/named/test.db`

```
@         IN       SOA     ns.example.com.  root.(
                                        2015123105 ; Serial
                                        28800      ; Refresh
                                        14400      ; Retry
                                        3600000    ; Expire
                                        86400 )    ; Minimum
               IN NS    ns.example.com.
ns             IN A     127.0.0.1
pc01           IN A     192.168.0.100
pc02           IN A     192.168.0.200
```

`ping`コマンドの結果

```
# ping pc01.example.com
PING pc01.example.com (192.168.0.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from server01.cluster.example.com (192.168.0.100): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.732 ms
64 bytes from server01.cluster.example.com (192.168.0.100): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.957 ms
64 bytes from server01.cluster.example.com (192.168.0.100): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.932 ms
64 bytes from server01.cluster.example.com (192.168.0.100): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.743 ms
64 bytes from server01.cluster.example.com (192.168.0.100): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.929 ms
```

本来は`pc01.example.com`でpingの結果が帰ってきてほしいのですが、
過去に設定したホスト名(`server01.cluster.example.com`)になってしまいます。

どの様に対処したらよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: 質問内容からすると、「逆引き」(IPアドレス→ホスト名)に関する質問に見えます。逆引きの設定はどうなっているでしょうか?

Comment: すみません。あまり理解していないのですが、`ping pc01.example.com`なのでホスト名→IPアドレスなので正引きではないのでしょか？

Comment: 過去に書かれたゾーンファイルのバックアップはありますか？あれば質問に記載願います。diffでも構いません。またどのようなファイルをどのように変更してどのようなコマンドを利用したか詳細な手順を教えてください

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントにもあった通り、逆引きの設定が`server01.cluster.example.com`なのが原因でした。